# QThread managment tasks

Tags: python, pyside2, qthread

How does qthread manage how many are being processed when I only have 4 threads max?
For example say I have 100 long processing tasks. What happens when I for loop through my 100 tree view items and emit a Qthread to process the each task? Does it automatically determine I only have 4 threads and process the 100 threads within the 4 available?

Curious.
Thanks

```
import os
import sys
import time
import random
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):
    
    finished = QtCore.Signal(object)

    def __init__(self, index):
        super(TaskThread, self).__init__()        
        self._index = index

    def runTask(self, task):
        self._task = task

    def run(self):
        t = random.randint(0,4)
        time.sleep(t)
        self.finished.emit(self._index)


class ExampleDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ExampleDialog, self).__init__()
        
        self.itemModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        self.uiListView = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.uiListView.setModel(self.itemModel)

        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.uiListView)

        self.populateItems()


    def populateItems(self):
        self.threads = []
        for x in range(100):
            output = 'C:/Users/JokerMartini-Asus/Desktop/Trash/thumbs/IMG_409{}.jpg'.format(x)

            # Item
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem('{}'.format(x))
            item.setData(QtGui.QPixmap(), QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole)
            item.setData(output, QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            self.itemModel.appendRow(item)

            mIndex = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(self.itemModel.indexFromItem(item))
            tt = TaskThread(mIndex)
            
            self.threads.append(tt)
            tt.start()
            tt.finished.connect(self.processFinished)


    def processFinished(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            model = index.model()
            model.setData(index, '{} updated'.format(index.row()), QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleDialog()
    window.resize(300,600)
    window.show()
    window.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What does "emit a QThread" mean? How exactly are you attempting to limit the number of threads? Your description is unclear, because you seem to be using "thread" to mean different things. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: added sample code

Comment: By "4 threads max" are you referring to the number of (logical) CPUs on your machine? If so, then any python multi-threading example will only ever use *one* of them at time. Using 100 threads is likely to be quite inefficient, since there could be lots of overhead from all the task switching. Your example code isn't very helpful, because it doesn't do any realistc work inside the threads. If the *actual* work is mostly IO-bound (*vs* CPU-bound.), that could make a huge difference. Python releases the GIL during IO operations, so true parallelism becomes possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: I'm basing this answer only to empirical experimentation and basic knowledge of threads. I don't have enough knowledge on the lower implementation of threads to provide reliable resources of what I'm expressing, nor I can certify that this is valid in the same way on all platforms Qt supports (I'm on Linux).</sup>

There are two important things to consider when dealing with threading, even with Qt bindings:

1. threading is not about "speeding up" things, but allowing computations to process when others are temporarily idle;
2. the GIL only allows *one* operation at a time for each process, the fact that we perceive an apparent "parallelism" is due to the fact that each thread is temporarily releasing control to another one;

Fundamentally speaking, there's no absolute order, and in python there's no strict priority for a thread (due to the above reasons): processing is theoretically done [almost] in the order of thread starting, but the results may vary depending on how "fast" the processing is done for each thread, even for identical operations. As soon as a thread releases control to the GIL, the "next" thread gets it.

You could see a slightly more reliable result by adding the following changes to your code:

```
class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):
    # ...
    def run(self):
        # always use the same timeout
        time.sleep(1)
        self.finished.emit(self._index)


class ExampleDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    # ...
    def processFinished(self, index):
        while app.hasPendingEvents():
            app.processEvents()
            time.sleep(.05)
        self.uiListView.repaint()
        # ...
```

<sup>Note: the above code will block the UI, `hasPendingEvents` has been considered obsolete exactly due to the concurrency of threading and the usage `processEvents` is discouraged for the same reason; consider it only for educational purposes.</sup>

This means three things:

- generally speaking, there's no "limit" to concurrent threads in python (since threads are not concurrent);
- heavy duty computations are not actually parallel in python with threads;
- most importantly, the number of "cores" is completely pointless when speaking about threads (especially in python): given the same situation, you'll get the same results for a 2-core CPU as you'd get for a 8-core CPU;

True parallelism can only be achieved through multiprocessing, but the problem is that processes, unlike threads, don't share memory. This doesn't mean that it's completely impossible: [this](https://elsampsa.github.io/valkka-examples/_build/html/qt_notes.html#python-multiprocessing) link claims they achieved a proper multiprocessing support for Qt signal/slot mechanism, but I never tried it and I cannot say it actually works (especially considering that that link is quite old).

<sup>Note: you shouldn't connect the signals of a thread *after* it has started, especially if the thread can possibly return immediately (`time.sleep(0)`); move the `tt.finished.connect` line *before* `tt.start()`.</sup>

Comment: Exceptional response I appreciate you breaking it down basic enough for me to understand. In my example above, where I have the time.sleep()... I'm actually running a command that downloads images off the internet and then once they are downloaded i display them in my ui. There are a few hundred images and I don't want to block my users with a frozen gui. So i was creating a QThread for every listitem and having it process downloading and emitting a signal when the image is ready for displaying.

Comment: I wasn't sure if what i was doing (creating a QThread) per item, and then deleting the QThread instance once the images is downloaded, was terrible practice or what...

Comment: @JokerMartini consider that [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) allows you to easily download objects using its native asynchronous API which doesn't block the event loop. For instance, you could subclass it, create a custom function for url requests with a callback parameter, then connect the `finished` signal of the network reply returned by [`get()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#get) with that callback. In this way you could also create your own "queueing" system to limit network usage or even provide a caching mechanism.

Comment: @JokerMartini also note that when talking about "parallelism" and "processing" I'm referring to *heavy-duty* work. As ekhumoro pointed out above, threading shows its benefits when dealing with IO access, like in your case: when you're downloading some content, the download process can require some *time*, but not actual *processing*. Downloading a 1mb file is not the same as processing its contents: the former takes time due to network interaction, so it *can* release control to other threads in the meantime, the latter requires processing and *won't* release control until it's finished.